# Searching and indexing hyphenated words with Whoosh

Tags: python, whoosh

I am using Whoosh to index and search a large number of documents, and many of the things I need to search on are hyphenated. Whoosh seems to treat hyphens as a special character of some kind, but for the life of me I can't figure out it's behavior.

Can anyone advise on how Whoosh treats hyphens while indexing and searching?

Comment: necroing this thread as I also cannot solve it

Comment: Does the answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Whoosh simply treats all punctuation as a space. Assuming a default `AND` search, the query `dual-scale thermometer` is equivalent to `dual AND scale AND thermometer`. This will find a document containing `dual-scale digital thermometer`, but it will also find `dual purpose bathroom scale with thermometer`.

One solution to avoid this is to turn the hyphenated words in your query into phrases: `"dual-scale" thermometer`, which is the equivalent of `"dual scale" AND thermometer`.

You could also force Whoosh to accept hyphens as part of a word. You do this by overriding the `RegexTokenizer` expression in the `StandardAnalyzer` with a regular expression that accepts hyphens as a valid part of a token.

```
    from whoosh import fields, analysis

    myanalyzer = analysis.StandardAnalyzer(expression=r'[\w-]+(\.?\w+)*')
    schema = fields.Schema(myfield=fields.TEXT(analyzer=myanalyzer))
```

Now a search for `dual-scale thermometer` is equivalent to `dual-scale AND thermometer` and will find `dual-scale digital thermometer` but not `"dual purpose bathroom scale with thermometer"`.

However, you won't be able to search for hyphenated words independently. If your document contained `high-quality components`, you would not match it if you searched for `quality`; only `high-quality`, because this has now become one token. Because of this side-effect, unless your content is strictly constrained in its use of hyphens to truly atomic hyphenated words, I would recommend the phrase approach.